# Losing router object on child component rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, react-hooks

I have a parent component `GoalList` which maps to a child component:

```
            {data.goals.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                    <Link
                        href={{ pathname: "/goal", query: { id: item.id } }}
                        key={`goal-item-${index}`}
                    >
                        <a>
                            <li>
                                <div>{item.title}</div>
                            </li>
                        </a>
                    </Link>
                );
            })}
```

`next/router`'s page:

```
import SingleGoal from "../components/SingleGoal";

const Single = () => {
    return <SingleGoal />;
};

export default Single;
```

Child Component:

```
const SingleGoal = () => {
    const [id, setId] = useState("");
    const router = useRouter();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (router.query.id !== "") setId(router.query.id);
    }, [router]);

    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(SINGLE_GOAL_QUERY, {
        variables: { id: id },
    });

    if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
    if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`;

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{data.goal.title}</h1>
            <p>{data.goal.endDate}</p>
        </div>
    );
};
```

When I click on `Link` in the parent component, the `item.id` is properly transferred and the `SINGLE_GOAL_QUERY` executes correctly.

BUT, when I refresh the `SingleGoal` component, the router object takes a split second to populate, and I get a GraphQL warning:

```
[GraphQL error]: Message: Variable "$id" of required type "ID!" was not provided., Location: [object Object], Path: undefined
```

On a similar project I had previously given props to next/router's page component, but this no longer seems to work:

```
const Single = (props) => {
    return <SingleGoal id={props.query.id} />;
};
```

How do I account for the delay in the router object? Is this a situation in which to use getInitialProps? 
Thank you for any direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the initial state inside your component with the router query id by reordering your hooks

```
const SingleGoal = () => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const [id, setId] = useState(router.query.id);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (router.query.id !== "") setId(router.query.id);
    }, [router]);

    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(SINGLE_GOAL_QUERY, {
        variables: { id: id },
    });

    if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
    if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`;

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{data.goal.title}</h1>
            <p>{data.goal.endDate}</p>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: It seems that this doesn't stop the `useQuery` from executing while the id is still undefined undefined. I get the same console warning about the ID not being provided

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the secret to props being transferred through via the `page` was to enable `getInitialProps` via a custom `_app`.

Before:

```
const MyApp = ({ Component, apollo, pageProps }) => {
    return (
        <ApolloProvider client={apollo}>
            <Page>
                <Component {...pageProps} />
            </Page>
        </ApolloProvider>
    );
};
```

After:

```
const MyApp = ({ Component, apollo, pageProps }) => {
    return (
        <ApolloProvider client={apollo}>
            <Page>
                <Component {...pageProps} />
            </Page>
        </ApolloProvider>
    );
};

MyApp.getInitialProps = async ({ Component, ctx }) => {
    let pageProps = {};

    if (Component.getInitialProps) {
        // calls page's `getInitialProps` and fills `appProps.pageProps`
        pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx);
    }
    // exposes the query to the user
    pageProps.query = ctx.query;
    return { pageProps };
};
```

The only downfall now is that there is no more static page generation, and server-side-rendering is used on each request.